# WIX cannot write value to registry if key contains space

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, wix, registry, webbrowser-control

I need to [enable IE feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for WebBrowser control. To emulate IE11, I need to write a value to registry key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

This manipulation need to be done during installation.
Here is my code in WIX script:

```
<?define var.IEFeatureEmulationKey = "Software\Microsoft\Internet    Explorer\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION" ?>
....
<Fragment>            
  <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">            
    <Component Id="registryValues" Guid="{some-guid}" >
      <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="$(var.IEFeatureEmulationKey)" Action="create">
        <RegistryValue Name="MyApp.EXE" Value="11000" Type="integer" Action="write"/>
      </RegistryKey>
    </Component>
</Fragment>
```

This code work only if **$(var.IEFeatureEmulationKey)** contains no spaces. But I need to write a value to this specific key.

Please help, how tell WiX to write value to registry even in registry key contains spaces.

UPD:
Added appropriate [issue](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5425) in WiX repository

Comment: Have you tried escaping the whitespacecharacter using `&#x20;`

Comment: This is what I get im my registry after escaping the space - http://prntscr.com/cvs25g

Comment: okay, scratch that ;)

Comment: Did you find a solution?  @Valentine

Comment: I've just used custom assembly written on C#, there're no such limitations with registry names and values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Still cannot overcome the issue, however I want to show a workaround that helped me.

I used custom action that allowed in WiX. First of all I added custom .NET assembly with following method within it

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult SetRegistryItems(Session session)
{
    session.Log("Begin SetRegistryItems");

    try
    {
        // this private method actually does manipulation with registry
        SetRegistry();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        session.Log(e.ToString());
    }

    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

Then this method should be referenced in WiX config file (.wxs)

```
<Fragment>    
  ...
  <CustomAction Id='SetRegistryItems' BinaryKey='<NameOfTheAssemblyWithoutExtension>' DllEntry='SetRegistryItems' Execute='immediate'/>
  ...
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    ...
    <Custom Action="SetRegistryItems" Before="LaunchConditions"/> 
    ...
  </InstallExecuteSequence> 
  ...
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This Blogpost](https://arunpp.wordpress.com/2014/06/13/variables-conditional-statements-in-wix/) uses some special syntax I have not seen before either. It states that variable can be defined this way, even if it contains a white space character like so:

```
<!–?define var.IEFeatureEmulationKey = "Software\Microsoft\Internet    Explorer\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION" ?>
```

The `!-` let aside, it looks quite similar to what you got. However, your value contains more than one whitespaces. I'm not sure if thats the value you truly want or if it was just for pointing the whitespace out clearly...

Comment: Not sure if it helps. First - this syntax makes Visual Studio to underline opening tag with red line. Second - this doesn't look like change value af a variable.
WiX behaves like cmd shell when you're trying to reach a directory with a space in its name. To overcome this problem in cmd, usually used quote signs (e.g. "dir name"). Is there similar syntax in WiX script?

Comment: "However, your value contains more than one whitespaces"
It's because of formatting in SO editor, in code there is only one space

Comment: i know that you can pass those preprocessor varialbes by cmd-params, which can also be set up permanently in VS (Project Settings). Maybe this might be a workaround... I have also read that some people had problem with this kind of issue and wrapped the whole cmd-param in quotes....